# Segmentation fault: 11 - But Build Successful

Tags: c#

I am creating a BlackJack game and so far I have created a Card Class
and Deck Class, I give my deck class a Print function to see if has created 
the Cards and shuffled them properly. But when I run the program I get this 
error, Segmentation fault: 11, but the build was successful.

**Main Class**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    namespace BlackJackGameX
    {
        public class MainClass
        {
            public static void Main (string[] args)
            {

                Deck CardDeck = new Deck();

                CardDeck.Print ();

            }
        }
    }
```

**Card Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BlackJackGameX
{
    public enum Suit {Spades, Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds}
    public enum FaceValue {Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King}

    public class Card
    {
        public Suit CardSuit;
        public FaceValue CardValue;
        public int iValue;

        public Card (Suit cardSuit, FaceValue cardValue, int ivalue)
        {
            CardSuit = cardSuit;
            CardValue = cardValue;
            iValue =ivalue;
        }

        public Card ()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Deck Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BlackJackGameX
{
    public class Deck
    {
        Random rNumber = new Random();

        List<Card> Cards;

        public int iValue1 = 11;
        public int iValue2 = 2;
        public int iValue3 = 3;
        public int iValue4 = 4;
        public int iValue5 = 5;
        public int iValue6 = 6;
        public int iValue7 = 7;
        public int iValue8 = 8;
        public int iValue9 = 9;
        public int iValue10 = 10;
        public int iValue11 = 10;
        public int iValue12 = 10;
        public int iValue13 = 10;

        public Deck()
        {
            Cards = NewDeck();
            Shuffle();
        }

        public void Shuffle()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i <= 51; ++i) 
            {
                int c = rNumber.Next (1, 53);

                Cards.Add(Cards[c]);
            }
        }

        private List<Card> NewDeck()
        {
            var AllSuits = new Suit[]
            {
                Suit.Spades,
                Suit.Hearts,
                Suit.Clubs,
                Suit.Diamonds
            };

            var AllFaces = new FaceValue[]
            {
                FaceValue.Ace,
                FaceValue.Two,
                FaceValue.Three,
                FaceValue.Four,
                FaceValue.Five,
                FaceValue.Six,
                FaceValue.Seven,
                FaceValue.Eight,
                FaceValue.Nine,
                FaceValue.Ten,
                FaceValue.Jack,
                FaceValue.Queen,
                FaceValue.King
            };

            var AllValues = new int[]
            {
                iValue1,
                iValue2,
                iValue3,
                iValue4,
                iValue5,
                iValue6,
                iValue7,
                iValue8,
                iValue9,
                iValue10,
                iValue11,
                iValue12,
                iValue13
            };

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 12; j++) 
                {
                    Card newCard = new Card(AllSuits[i], AllFaces[j], AllValues[j]);
                    NewDeck().Add(newCard);
                }
            }

            return NewDeck();
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Cards[1].CardSuit);
            Console.WriteLine(Cards[1].CardValue);
            Console.WriteLine(Cards[1].iValue);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are recursively calling newDeck() a lot in places that dont make much sense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the class `Deck` in the method `private List<Card> NewDeck()`. When you write `NewDeck().Add(newCard);` you are calling the function recursive again and again until a stackoverflow occurs. The solution is to define a new local `List<Card>` variable for your deck where you are adding cards to and returning this variable instead of `NewDeck()`.

Just before your two for loops add `List<Card> myDeck = new List<Card>();` and change the line `NewDeck().Add(newCard);` to `myDeck.Add(newCard);` and the `return NewDeck();` to `return myDeck;`.

Comment: Overflowing the stack is indeed yet an other way to get a segmentation fault.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much, i've been trying to get this working for days [:

Answer (score 1):

When a build is successful, it means that the compiler was able to generate the targeted binary from your code. However it does not mean that your app is without bugs. It just means that the compilation was successful.

A `Segmentation fault` is a memory error, which occurs at runtime. So you must first have a successful build. This is expected.

What you need to do is debug your code to determine why this memory error is occurring.

Are you dereferencing a NULL pointer? Are you performing operations beyond the limits of an array? Are you overflowing a buffer (and overwriting a pointer)? These are common cause for a seg. fault. error.

So, I would say your question is more about debugging (how to debug a segmentation fault error). For that, we need to know in what circumstances the error occurs.